# vertically stacked list - can't iterate through them?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I'm trying to filter different columns of a dataframe to keep values already defined in a dictionary. I wrote a function to do this:

```
def replace_gym(x):
for i in list(amenities_dict['Gym']):
    if x == i:
        return(x)
```

and then apply the function for the column:

```
transdf['Gym'] = transdf['Gym'].apply(lambda x: replace_gym(x))
```

Now for some reason it only applies to the very first item in the amenities list - it seems like it doesn't iterate through the list. All the values in the column are "Gym". (that's the first item in the list)

The *list(amenities_dict['Gym'])* (ie the list that's associated with the 'Gym' key in the amenities_dict dictionary) looks like this:

[vertical vs horizontal list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHdEI.png)

Below that is an example with a test list. With the test list manually defined, it works and it keep all values (manicure, pedicure etc...)

```
testlist = ['Manicure', 'Pedicure', 'Bowling', 'Casino']

def replace_test(x):
    for i in testlist:
        if x == i:
            return(x)

transdf['Gym'] = transdf['Gym'].apply(lambda x: replace_test(x))
```

So I figure Python has a different way of iterating through a "vertical" versus a "horizontal" list? As you see the code is exactly the same, it's the lists that change. Any way I can make them equivalent? (ie turn the Gym list horizontal)

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the answers. Found the mistake!

Sloppy from my part, but I left a line of code in which actually uses the inverted amenities_dict to replace values (for example, all 'Fitness Centre" like strings to 'Gym')

Deleting that line solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are both just normal lists, there is no "vertical" or "horizontal" list there. The only reason they are listed with a different orientation is because one has longer items.

Also if `amenities_dict['Gym']` already is a list, i.e. if the value for the key `Gym` is already a list, then you don't need to do `list(amenities_dict['Gym'])`